# debug javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a javascript thats breaking. Now Is there a way i can call the function from content editor web part and debug to see where the hick up is?

Comment: Mina, I don't think your question can be answered (as Marc mentioned below). Can you add some more specific information to help us solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Developer Tools available in Internet Explorer, enable Debugging and it should break when the error comes up.

Comment: +1, you can also use Firebug in FireFox.

Comment: okay, i added debugger keyword in the cewp where it calls the function. also, have the developer tools open. i refresh the page and i can see error warning on the ie status bar. but developer tool is doing nothing.

Comment: @mina you will need to goto the script tab and start debugging.

Answer (score 2):

There are some skills around debugging JavaScript that you'll need to learn. Firebug and the IE Developer Tools (or equivalent in Chrome, etc.) are the tools, but you'll need to learn how to use them well.  There's not really an "answer" to your question.

Generally, you'll have syntax errors like missing commas, brackets, parentheses, or semicolons. That's always the first thing I look for in my scripts.